# Symfony 2.0.12 update: ERROR METADATA

Tags: symfony

I have updated my symfony version to 2.0.12 version.

But I have this error changing the deps, and deps.lock file

> Installing/Updating metadata
>   fatal: ambiguous argument '1.0.0': unknown revision or path not in the working tree.
>   Use '--' to separate paths from revisions

```
metadata
  git=http://github.com/schmittjoh/metadata.git
  version=1.0.0
```

***deps.lock file***

```
metadata 1.0.0
```

Comment: Could you be more clear? What did you do (change deps, deps.lock? Run any command?) and where do you see the error?

Comment: Hi boo. I have change deps and deps.lock file. and run php bin/vendors install

Comment: Did you try ``php bin/vendors install --reinstall``? I had a look at my deps/deps.lock and they look the same, so there is no obvious error in there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved my problem. I have changed the **deps.lock** with the previous metadata branch id:

I mean I have made:

```
        metadata 30c622cad82e39a6856b981a9bfb9df06b3cc067
```

Hope it will help other people.

See ya

Sam

Answer (score 0):

metadata should have version 1.1.0 in `deps.lock` and `deps`. Also make sure that your `bin/vendors` is exactly as in symfony-standard ([link to file](https://raw.github.com/symfony/symfony-standard/2.0/bin/vendors))